# Error from a non-sharable field defined in a subgraph that shoudn't have this field

Tags: graphql, nestjs, apollo-server, apollo-federation, apollo-gateway

I have multiple GraphQL microservices (subgraphs, using ApolloFederationDriver) with a GraphQL gateway (using ApolloGatewayDriver)

I have a really strange bug since I've upgraded my GraphQL microservices and gateway to use `@apollo/server` (`@nestjs/graphql@11` + `@nestjs/apollo@11`) : I have an error when my subgraphs are composed telling me that subgraph A has a non shareable field from an object type subgraph B and so it is not happy with. I would ok with this error, the problem is that subgraph A doesn't have the mentionned entity from the subgraph B and I don't know why I got this error.

For information, I have a monorepo, which contains a package where all my object types are defined and exported
I know this is quite strange, let me know  if you have any idea where this error could come from.

Thanks :)

EDIT 1: So it seems that if one of my ObjectType has a `@Field(() => AnotherObjectType`, `AnotherObjectType` will be included in every subgraph schemas. Is this behavior expected?

EDIT 2: Here is an example based on a NestJS sample: https://github.com/MrSquaare/31-graphql-federation-code-first. I got errors because `posts-application` uses non-sharable fields from `User` model (which is normal) But I also got errors because `somethings-application` uses non-sharable fields from `User` model, which is not normal since `somethings-application` doesn't use the `User` model

Comment: Can you please attach the exact issue or error message if you haven't resolved it yet?

Comment: @adarsh Here is the error with the example I provided

`Error: A valid schema couldn't be composed. The following composition errors were found:
 Non-shareable field "User.name" is resolved from multiple subgraphs: it is resolved from subgraphs "posts", "somethings" and "users" and defined as non-shareable in all of them`

Comment: did you figure this out? Im running into the same issue.

Comment: @ChrisPawlukiewicz Hello, sorry for the late reply! No sadly I didn't find a way to resolve this...

Comment: I found out that the issue is because in the monorepo because the code is included, the type declarations are added. You can see this in your dist.js. I fixed this by excluding those libraries from my dockerfile.

Comment: running into the exact same issue after updating to federation 2, anyone had any luck @ChrisPawlukiewicz

Answer (score 0):

I recently came across with this issue and was I was able to solve this by adding

> @Directive('@key(fields: "id")')

on top of those mentioned entities.

*In my case I was using @nestjs/graphql with code-first approach.*

Answer (score 0):

Make your User type "shareable":

```
import { Directive, Field, ID, ObjectType } from '@nestjs/graphql';

@ObjectType()
@Directive('@key(fields: "id")')
@Directive('@shareable') //this is missing in your implementation
export class User {
    @Field((type) => ID)
    id: number;

    @Field((type) => String)
    name: string;
}
```

For more information: https://www.apollographql.com/docs/federation/federated-types/sharing-types/#using-shareable